# ActivityNotFoundException using product flavors

Tags: android, gradle

I'm playing with product flavors in Android Studio and have hit a bump...!

I have set up two product flavors in the build.gradle file

productFlavors {

```
    pro {
        packageName "com.foo.bar.pro"
    }

    free {
        packageName "com.foo.bar.free"
    }
}
```

This builds fine and will install onto a device.

The problem I have is that I added a startActivity call into the MainActivity class which is in the /src/main/java.... folder. The 'free' debug build complains that it cannot find the explicit class com.foo.bar.free.....

I thought that this would be handled.. But do I need to do something specific?﻿

Comment: Please show your manifest where you have declared this activity and how you are starting it (assuming that the problem comes from a `startActivity()` call of yours).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the activity was declared in the manifest as .SetupActivity. I changed it to the fully qualified name and it worked!